# Why does my modified (real world haskell) Mapreduce implementation fails with "Too many open files"

Tags: mapreduce, haskell

I am implementing a haskell program wich compares each line of a file with each other line in the file. For symplicity let's assume the datastructure represented by one line is just an Int, and my algorithm is the squared distance. This would I implement as follows:

```
--My operation
distance :: Int -> Int -> Int
distance a b = (a-b)*(a-b)

combineDistances :: [Int] -> Int
combineDistances = sum

--Applying my operation simply on a file
sumOfDistancesOnSmallFile :: FilePath -> IO Int
sumOfDistancesOnSmallFile path = do
              fileContents <- readFile path
              return $ allDistances $ map read $ lines $ fileContents
              where
                  allDistances (x:xs) = (allDistances xs) + ( sum $ map (distance x) xs)
                  allDistances _ = 0

--Test file generation
createTestFile :: Int -> FilePath -> IO ()
createTestFile n path = writeFile path $ unlines $ map show $ take n $ infiniteList 0 1
    where infiniteList :: Int->Int-> [Int]
          infiniteList i j = (i + j) : infiniteList j (i+j)
```

Unfortunately the complete file will be kept in memory. To prevent possible out of memory exceptions on very big files, i would like to seek the filecursor back to the beginning of the file, at each recursion of 'allDistances'.

In the book "Real World Haskell" an implementation is given of mapreduce, with a function to split a file in chunks (chapter 24, available [here](http://book.realworldhaskell.org/read/concurrent-and-multicore-programming.html)). I modified the chunking function to, instead of dividing the complete file in chunks, return as many chunks as lines with each chunk representing one element of

```
tails . lines. readFile
```

The full implementation is (plus the previous code region)

```
import qualified Data.ByteString.Lazy.Char8 as Lazy
import Control.Exception (bracket,finally)
import Control.Monad(forM,liftM)
import Control.Parallel.Strategies
import Control.Parallel
import Control.DeepSeq (NFData)
import Data.Int (Int64)
import System.IO

--Applying my operation using mapreduce on a very big file
sumOfDistancesOnFile :: FilePath -> IO Int
sumOfDistancesOnFile path = chunkedFileOperation chunkByLinesTails (distancesUsingMapReduce) path

distancesUsingMapReduce :: [Lazy.ByteString] -> Int
distancesUsingMapReduce = mapReduce rpar (distancesFirstToTail . lexer)
                                rpar combineDistances
              where lexer :: Lazy.ByteString -> [Int]
                    lexer chunk = map (read . Lazy.unpack) (Lazy.lines chunk)

distancesOneToMany :: Int -> [Int] -> Int
distancesOneToMany one many = combineDistances $ map (distance one) many

distancesFirstToTail :: [Int] -> Int
distancesFirstToTail s = 
              if not (null s)
              then distancesOneToMany (head s) (tail s)
              else 0
--The mapreduce algorithm
mapReduce :: Strategy b -- evaluation strategy for mapping
      -> (a -> b)   -- map function
      -> Strategy c -- evaluation strategy for reduction
      -> ([b] -> c) -- reduce function
      -> [a]        -- list to map over
      -> c
mapReduce mapStrat mapFunc reduceStrat reduceFunc input =
      mapResult `pseq` reduceResult
      where mapResult    = parMap mapStrat mapFunc input
            reduceResult = reduceFunc mapResult `using` reduceStrat


--Working with (file)chunks:
data ChunkSpec = CS{
    chunkOffset :: !Int64
    , chunkLength :: !Int64
    } deriving (Eq,Show)

chunkedFileOperation ::   (NFData a)=>
            (FilePath-> IO [ChunkSpec])
       ->   ([Lazy.ByteString]-> a)
       ->   FilePath
       ->   IO a
chunkedFileOperation chunkCreator funcOnChunks path = do
    (chunks, handles)<- chunkedRead chunkCreator path
    let r = funcOnChunks chunks
    (rdeepseq r `seq` return r) `finally` mapM_ hClose handles

chunkedRead ::  (FilePath -> IO [ChunkSpec])
        ->  FilePath
        ->  IO ([Lazy.ByteString], [Handle])
chunkedRead chunkCreator path = do
    chunks <- chunkCreator path
    liftM unzip . forM chunks $ \spec -> do
    h <- openFile path ReadMode
    hSeek h AbsoluteSeek (fromIntegral (chunkOffset spec))
    chunk <- Lazy.take (chunkLength spec) `liftM` Lazy.hGetContents h
    return (chunk,h)

-- returns set of chunks representing  tails . lines . readFile 
chunkByLinesTails :: FilePath -> IO[ChunkSpec]
chunkByLinesTails path = do
    bracket (openFile path ReadMode) hClose $ \h-> do
        totalSize <- fromIntegral `liftM` hFileSize h
        let chunkSize = 1
            findChunks offset = do
            let newOffset = offset + chunkSize
            hSeek h AbsoluteSeek (fromIntegral newOffset)
            let findNewline lineSeekOffset = do
                eof <- hIsEOF h
                if eof
                    then return [CS offset (totalSize - offset)]
                    else do
                        bytes <- Lazy.hGet h 4096
                        case Lazy.elemIndex '\n' bytes of
                            Just n -> do
                                nextChunks <- findChunks (lineSeekOffset + n + 1)
                                return (CS offset (totalSize-offset):nextChunks)
                            Nothing -> findNewline (lineSeekOffset + Lazy.length bytes)
            findNewline newOffset
        findChunks 0
```

Unfortunately, on a bigger file (for example 2000 lines) the mapreduce version throws an exception:
*** Exception: getCurrentDirectory: resource exhausted (Too many open files)

I'm a bit ashamed to not be able to debug the program myself, but I only know how to debug java/c# code. And I also don't know how the file chunking and reading could be properly tested. I expect the problem not to be part of the mapreduce function itself, as a similar version without mapreduce also throws an exception. In that attempt I had the chunkedFileOperation accept both the operation for one chunk and the 'reduce' function, which it applied directly.

Btw, I'm running
 HaskellPlatform 2011.2.0 on Mac OS X 10.6.7 (snow leopard)
with the following packages:
 bytestring 0.9.1.10
 parallel 3.1.0.1
and i qualify as a self-educated beginner/fresh haskell programmer

Comment: On stack overflow, you should not post a signature. Your account's name is displayed in the box right under your question.

Comment: With the following import:  

    import qualified Data.ByteString.Char8 as Lazy  

and the following chunk:  

    data ChunkSpec = CS{
        chunkOffset :: !Int
        , chunkLength :: !Int
        } deriving (Eq,Show)

the program works on big files.

Comment: My initial attempt to use iteratee IO unfortunately failed, on which I ask help in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5856435/why-does-my-mapreduce-implementation-real-world-haskell-using-iteratee-io-also)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're using lazy IO, so those files opened with `readFile` aren't being closed in a timely fashion. You'll need to think of a solution that explicitly closes the files regularly (e.g. via strict IO, or iteratee IO).

Comment: Ah, so i'm applying two memory lowering solutions

Comment: But is the lazy IO causing the mapReduce's pseq to spawn too many threads, or does it delay the finally - hClose in chunkedFileOperation. This part of the book's example isn't really clear to me, as I read it to finally "release all handles" instead of releasing each handle it just rdeepseq'ed into.

Comment: No, there's not too many threads. There are too many opened files (because they're being closed lazily, when the GC decides they're not needed).

Answer (score 0):

This error means exactly what it says: your process has too many files open. The OS imposes an arbitrary limit on the number of files (or directories) which a process can simultaneously read. See your `ulimit(1)` manpage and/or limit the number of mappers.

Comment: I know there's a limit on the number of file handles, but I expected my algorithm to use at most the number of threads created by ghc, which should be very low (at least, that is the intention of the implementation)