# Why does my Mapreduce implementation (real world haskell) using iteratee IO also fails with "Too many open files"

Tags: loops, haskell, mapreduce

I am implementing a haskell program which compares each line of a file with each other line in the file. Which can be implemented **single threaded** as follows

```
distance :: Int -> Int -> Int
distance a b = (a-b)*(a-b)

sumOfDistancesOnSmallFile :: FilePath -> IO Int
sumOfDistancesOnSmallFile path = do
              fileContents <- readFile path
              return $ allDistances $ map read $ lines $ fileContents
              where
                  allDistances (x:xs) = (allDistances xs) + ( sum $ map (distance x) xs)
                  allDistances _ = 0
```

This will run in O(n^2) time, and has to keep the complete list of integers in memory the whole time. In my actual program the line contains more numbers, out of which I construct a slightly more complex datatype than Int. This gave me out of memory errors on the data I have to process.

So there are two improvements to be made to the above-mentioned single threaded solution. First, speed up the actual running time. Second, find a way to not keep the whole list in memory the full time. I know this requires parsing the complete file n times. Thus there will be O(n^2) comparisons, and O(n^2) lines parsed. This is OK for me as I'd rather have a slow successful program than a failing program. When the input file is small enough I can always reside to a simpler version.

To use multiple cpu cores I took the Mapreduce implementation out of Real World Haskell (chapter 24, available [here](http://book.realworldhaskell.org/read/concurrent-and-multicore-programming.html)).

I modified the chunking function from the book to, instead of dividing the complete file in chunks, return as many chunks as lines with each chunk representing one element of

```
tails . lines . readFile
```

Because I want the program also to be scalable in file-size, I initially used **lazy IO**. This however fails with "Too many open files", about which I asked in a [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5541784/why-does-my-modified-real-world-haskell-mapreduce-implementation-fails-with-to) (the file handles were disposed too late by the GC). The full lazy IO version is posted there.

As the accepted answer explains, **strict IO** could solve the issue. That indeed solves the "Too many open files" problem for 2k line files, but fails with "out of memory" on a 50k file.

Note that the first **single threaded** implementation (without mapreduce) is capable of handling a 50k file.

The alternative solution, which also appeals most to me, is to use **iteratee IO**. I expected this to solve both the file handle, and memory resource exhaustion. My implementation however still fails with a "Too many open files" error on a 2k line file.

The iteratee IO version has the same *mapReduce* function as in the book, but has a modified *chunkedFileEnum* to let it work with an *Enumerator*.

Thus my question is; what is wrong with the following iteratee IO base implementation? Where is the Laziness?.

```
import Control.Monad.IO.Class (liftIO)
import Control.Monad.Trans (MonadIO, liftIO)
import System.IO

import qualified Data.Enumerator.List as EL
import qualified Data.Enumerator.Text as ET
import Data.Enumerator hiding (map, filter, head, sequence)

import Data.Text(Text)
import Data.Text.Read
import Data.Maybe

import qualified Data.ByteString.Char8 as Str
import Control.Exception (bracket,finally)
import Control.Monad(forM,liftM)
import Control.Parallel.Strategies
import Control.Parallel
import Control.DeepSeq (NFData)
import Data.Int (Int64)

--Goal: in a file with n values, calculate the sum of all n*(n-1)/2 squared distances

--My operation for one value pair
distance :: Int -> Int -> Int
distance a b = (a-b)*(a-b)

combineDistances :: [Int] -> Int
combineDistances = sum

--Test file generation
createTestFile :: Int -> FilePath -> IO ()
createTestFile n path = writeFile path $ unlines $ map show $ take n $ infiniteList 0 1
        where infiniteList :: Int->Int-> [Int]
              infiniteList i j = (i + j) : infiniteList j (i+j)

--Applying my operation simply on a file 
--(Actually does NOT throw an Out of memory on a file generated by createTestFile 50000)
--But I want to use multiple cores..
sumOfDistancesOnSmallFile :: FilePath -> IO Int
sumOfDistancesOnSmallFile path = do
                  fileContents <- readFile path
                  return $ allDistances $ map read $ lines $ fileContents
                  where
                      allDistances (x:xs) = (allDistances xs) + ( sum $ map (distance x)    xs)
                      allDistances _ = 0

--Setting up an enumerator of read values from a text stream
readerEnumerator :: Monad m =>Integral a => Reader a -> Step a m b -> Iteratee Text m b
readerEnumerator reader = joinI . (EL.concatMapM transformer)
                            where transformer input = case reader input of
                                         Right (val, remainder) -> return [val]
                                         Left err -> return [0]

readEnumerator :: Monad m =>Integral a => Step a m b -> Iteratee Text m b
readEnumerator = readerEnumerator (signed decimal)

--The iteratee version of my operation
distancesFirstToTailIt :: Monad m=> Iteratee Int m Int
distancesFirstToTailIt = do
    maybeNum <- EL.head
    maybe (return 0) distancesOneToManyIt maybeNum

distancesOneToManyIt :: Monad m=> Int -> Iteratee Int m Int
distancesOneToManyIt base = do
    maybeNum <- EL.head
    maybe (return 0) combineNextDistance maybeNum
    where combineNextDistance nextNum = do
              rest <- distancesOneToManyIt base
              return $ combineDistances [(distance base nextNum),rest]

--The mapreduce algorithm
mapReduce :: Strategy b -- evaluation strategy for mapping
          -> (a -> b)   -- map function
          -> Strategy c -- evaluation strategy for reduction
          -> ([b] -> c) -- reduce function
          -> [a]        -- list to map over
          -> c
mapReduce mapStrat mapFunc reduceStrat reduceFunc input =
          mapResult `pseq` reduceResult
          where mapResult    = parMap mapStrat mapFunc input
                reduceResult = reduceFunc mapResult `using` reduceStrat

--Applying the iteratee operation using mapreduce
sumOfDistancesOnFileWithIt :: FilePath -> IO Int
sumOfDistancesOnFileWithIt path = chunkedFileEnum chunkByLinesTails (distancesUsingMapReduceIt) path

distancesUsingMapReduceIt :: [Enumerator Text IO Int] -> IO Int
distancesUsingMapReduceIt = mapReduce rpar (runEnumeratorAsMapFunc)
                                      rpar (sumValuesAsReduceFunc)
                            where runEnumeratorAsMapFunc :: Enumerator Text IO Int -> IO Int
                                  runEnumeratorAsMapFunc = (\source->run_ (source $$ readEnumerator $$ distancesFirstToTailIt))
                                  sumValuesAsReduceFunc :: [IO Int] -> IO Int
                                  sumValuesAsReduceFunc = liftM sum . sequence
                              

--Working with (file)chunk enumerators:
data ChunkSpec = CS{
    chunkOffset :: !Int
    , chunkLength :: !Int
    } deriving (Eq,Show)

chunkedFileEnum ::   (NFData (a)) => MonadIO m =>
                (FilePath-> IO [ChunkSpec])
           ->   ([Enumerator Text m b]->IO a)
           ->   FilePath
           ->   IO a
chunkedFileEnum chunkCreator funcOnChunks path = do
    (chunks, handles)<- chunkedEnum chunkCreator path
    r <- funcOnChunks chunks
    (rdeepseq r `seq` (return r)) `finally` mapM_ hClose handles

chunkedEnum ::  MonadIO m=>
                (FilePath -> IO [ChunkSpec])
            ->  FilePath
            ->  IO ([Enumerator Text m b], [Handle])
chunkedEnum chunkCreator path = do
    chunks <- chunkCreator path
    liftM unzip . forM chunks $ \spec -> do
        h <- openFile path ReadMode
        hSeek h AbsoluteSeek (fromIntegral (chunkOffset spec))
        let chunk = ET.enumHandle h --Note:chunklength not taken into account, so just to EOF
        return (chunk,h)

-- returns set of chunks representing  tails . lines . readFile 
chunkByLinesTails :: FilePath -> IO[ChunkSpec]
chunkByLinesTails path = do
    bracket (openFile path ReadMode) hClose $ \h-> do
        totalSize <- fromIntegral `liftM` hFileSize h
        let chunkSize = 1
            findChunks offset = do
            let newOffset = offset + chunkSize
            hSeek h AbsoluteSeek (fromIntegral newOffset)
            let findNewline lineSeekOffset = do
                eof <- hIsEOF h
                if eof
                    then return [CS offset (totalSize - offset)]
                    else do
                        bytes <- Str.hGet h 256
                        case Str.elemIndex '\n' bytes of
                            Just n -> do
                                nextChunks <- findChunks (lineSeekOffset + n + 1)
                                return (CS offset (totalSize-offset):nextChunks)
                            Nothing -> findNewline (lineSeekOffset + Str.length bytes)
            findNewline newOffset
        findChunks 0
```

Btw, I'm running
HaskellPlatform 2011.2.0 on Mac OS X 10.6.7 (snow leopard)
with the following packages:
bytestring 0.9.1.10
parallel 3.1.0.1
enumerator 0.4.8 , with a manual [here](http://www.yesodweb.com/book/enumerator)

Comment: You have too much parallelism. With a chunksize of 1 and a 2k line file, you're opening the file 2k times. And the more parallelism, the more memory you use as well. I really don't think that a problem like this, requiring crossing a structure with itself, is suited to the parallelization strategy you've chosen. You should set a reasonably large chunk size, and do your calculations within each chunk and then across chunks.

Comment: To harp on this further, you're taking an operation that's potentially linear in space and disk reads and turning it into an operation that's n^2 in space and disk reads. Laziness and strictness of the reads just trades off between running out of filedescriptors or running out of memory to hold all the results of the reads. Either way this is just the wrong approach.

Comment: Shouldn't _pseq_ be smart enough not to spawn all 2k threads immediately? I regard them more like jobs. They all have to be done sometime, and by using _pseq_ I try to tell haskell that it might optimize running time by running some in parallel.

Comment: ps, i'm actually deliberately running an n^2 algorithm, as I need to compare each element with each other element. The total required space at any moment can however be much smaller, as I do not need to keep the whole list of elements (linear) in memory. I just iterate n times through the whole list. Because n^2 algorithms are always slow, I try to get the best out of it by making it parallel.

Comment: The algorithm is necessarily n^2 in time, sure, but your implementation that is also n^2 in space and disk reads, and doesn't have to be. You're not sparking threads, you're sparking evaluations of expressions to weak head normal form, which may be executed across available OS threads. However, the runtime also can interleave evaluating these sparks, especially if they block on, e.g., disk IO. In any case, if you ask the runtime to spark 2k evaluations at once, you shouldn't be surprised when it takes you up on your offer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As the error says, there are too many open files. I expected Haskell to run most of the program sequentially, but some 'sparks' parallel. However, as sclv mentioned, Haskell always sparks the evaluations.

This usually is not a problem in a pure functional program, but it is when dealing with IO (resources). I scaled the parallelism as described in the Real World Haskell book too far up. So my conclusion is to do parallelism only on a limited scale when dealing with IO resources within the sparks. In the pure functional part, excessive parallelism may succeed.

Thus the answer to my post is, to not use MapReduce on the whole program, but within an inner pure functional part.

To show where the program actually failed, i configured it with --enable-executable-profiling -p, build it, and ran it using +RTS -p -hc -L30. Because the executable fails immediately, there is no memory allocation profile. The resulting time allocation profile in the .prof file starts with the following:

```
                                                                                               individual    inherited
COST CENTRE              MODULE                                               no.    entries  %time %alloc   %time %alloc

MAIN                     MAIN                                                   1            0   0.0    0.3   100.0  100.0
  main                    Main                                                1648           2   0.0    0.0    50.0   98.9
    sumOfDistancesOnFileWithIt MapReduceTest                                  1649           1   0.0    0.0    50.0   98.9
      chunkedFileEnum       MapReduceTest                                     1650           1   0.0    0.0    50.0   98.9
        chunkedEnum          MapReduceTest                                    1651         495   0.0   24.2    50.0   98.9
          lineOffsets         MapReduceTest                                   1652           1  50.0   74.6    50.0   74.6
```

chunkedEnum returns IO ([Enumerator Text m b], [Handle]), and apparently receives 495 entries. The input file was a 2k line file, so the single entry on lineOffsets returned a list of 2000 offsets. There is not a single entry in distancesUsingMapReduceIt, so the actual work did not even start!