# Haskell batched file processing does not improve space profile

Tags: haskell, profiling, heap-memory

I have a simple algorithm to implement: compare each line with each other line. Each line contains one number, and the comparison function is the distance. The sum of all distances is the final result.

This can be implemented as simply as follows:

```
sumOfDistancesOnSmallFile :: FilePath -> IO Integer
sumOfDistancesOnSmallFile path = withFile path ReadMode $ \h->do
                          distances <- liftM ( (map textRead) ) $ hListToEOF Text.hGetLine h
                          let subSet = drop offset distances
                          let emptySubSet = null subSet
                          return $ if (emptySubSet)
                                           then (0)
                                           else (distancesManyToMany subSet)

hListToEOF :: (Handle -> IO a) -> Handle -> IO [a]
hListToEOF func h = do
    element <- func h
    atEOF <- hIsEOF h
    rest <- case(atEOF) of
        True -> return []
        False -> hListToEOF func h
    return $ element:rest

distancesManyToMany :: [Integer]->Integer
distancesManyToMany (x:xs) = distancesOneToMany x xs + (distancesManyToMany xs)
distancesManyToMany _ = 0

distancesOneToMany :: Integer -> [Integer] -> Integer
distancesOneToMany one many = sum $ map (distance one) many

distance :: Integer -> Integer -> Integer
distance a b = (a-b)
```

To get reasonable big data on each line, i've used the following file generator:

```
createTestFile :: Int -> FilePath -> IO ()
createTestFile n path = writeFile path $ unlines $ map show $ take n $ infiniteList 0 1
    where infiniteList :: Integer->Integer-> [Integer]
          infiniteList i j = (i+j) * (i+j) : infiniteList j (i+j)
```

A 2000 line file, of 840kb will take 1.92 seconds and 1.5Gb allocations, with a maximum usage of around 1.5Mb.

A 6k line file, of 7.5mb will take 22 seconds, 34Gb allocations, with a maximum memory usage of around 15Mb

Unfortunately my data will be millions of lines. I initially attempted to improve speed (about which I asked in 2 previous posts about [MapReduce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5541784/why-does-my-modified-real-world-haskell-mapreduce-implementation-fails-with-to) combined with [Iteratee IO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5856435/why-does-my-mapreduce-implementation-real-world-haskell-using-iteratee-io-also)), but the actual limiting problem is space.

**Intermediate thought**:This could be overcome by reading the complete file for each number to compare. This does take a lot of additional time, because the file needs to be opened and parsed for each line that is to be compared with the remainder of the file. Also the number of memory allocations will become quadratic. So that's not really useful as a final solution

**The final step**:
That was my first step towards my goal: batched execution. I would like to take a few k lines into memory. Apply the ManyToMany algorithm on those in memory. Then, iterate through the remainder of the file. On each iteration step, only one successive line needs to be read and parsed, which then can be compared to all items in the memory batch.

By choosing a batch size big enough the file does not have to be re-read often. My implementation is as follows:

```
sumOfDistancesOnBigFileUsingBatches :: FilePath -> Int -> Int -> IO Integer
sumOfDistancesOnBigFileUsingBatches path batchSize offset = do
                      (firstResult, maybeRecurse) <- singleResultBatch path batchSize offset
                      recursiveResult <- case maybeRecurse of
                                             Nothing -> return 0
                                             Just newOffset -> sumOfDistancesOnBigFileUsingBatches path batchSize newOffset
                      return $ firstResult + recursiveResult

singleResultBatch :: FilePath -> Int -> Int -> IO(Integer, Maybe Int)
singleResultBatch path batchSize offset = withFile path ReadMode $ \h->do
                          distances <- readDistances h
                          let (batch, subSet) = splitAt batchSize $ drop offset distances
                          let batchInner = distancesManyToMany batch
                          let recursionTerminated = null subSet
                          let (batchToSubSet, newOffset) = if (recursionTerminated)
                                              then (0, Nothing)
                                              else (distancesSetToSet batch subSet, Just (offset+batchSize))
                          return (batchInner+batchToSubSet, newOffset)
                          where
                            readDistances h = liftM ( (map textRead) ) $ hListToEOF Text.hGetLine h


distancesSetToSet :: [Integer] -> [Integer] -> Integer
distancesSetToSet xs ys = sum $ map (\one->distancesOneToMany one xs) ys
```

On the 2k line file, with a batch size of 500 it finished with 2.16secs, 2.2Gb allocations and around 6Mb required space. That is 4 times the space of the simplest version! It might be coincidence, but there are also 4 batches utilized...

What surprised me, is that all the required space is consumed initially, later on the required space only decreases. This becomes a problem with a 50k line file (500MB), because then it runs out of memory.

**My question is:** why does the batches solution consume more memory? It seems to keep the whole file in memory for each batch, even though it should (at least that's my intention) only keep one single batch in memory.

**EDIT**:
I removed the details of the 6k line file and 500line batches (I took a wrong profile file)

And as addition, here is the space profile generated using the 2k line file and 500line batches:
[image: space profile of batched solution on 2k line file (840KB)]

**EDIT2**:
Profiling with retainer resulted in:

```
total time  =        2.24 secs   (112 ticks @ 20 ms)
total alloc = 2,126,803,896 bytes  (excludes profiling overheads)

COST CENTRE                    MODULE               %time %alloc

textRead                       MapReduceTestStrictStrings  47.3   44.4
distance                       MapReduceTestStrictStrings  25.9   25.3
distancesOneToMany             MapReduceTestStrictStrings  18.8   29.5
singleResultBatch              MapReduceTestStrictStrings   4.5    0.0
readTextDevice                 Data.Text.IO.Internal   2.7    0.0


                                                                                               individual    inherited
COST CENTRE              MODULE                                               no.    entries  %time %alloc   %time %alloc

MAIN                     MAIN                                                   1           0   0.0    0.0   100.0  100.0
 main                    Main                                                1604           2   0.0    0.0   100.0  100.0
  sumOfDistancesOnBigFileUsingBatches MapReduceTestStrictStrings                          1605           4   0.0    0.0   100.0  100.0
   singleResultBatch     MapReduceTestStrictStrings                          1606          20   4.5    0.0   100.0  100.0
    distancesSetToSet    MapReduceTestStrictStrings                          1615           3   0.0    0.0    34.8   43.3
     distancesOneToMany  MapReduceTestStrictStrings                          1616        3000  14.3   23.2    34.8   43.2
      distance           MapReduceTestStrictStrings                          1617     1500000  20.5   20.0    20.5   20.0
    textRead             MapReduceTestStrictStrings                          1614        5000  47.3   44.4    47.3   44.4
    distancesManyToMany  MapReduceTestStrictStrings                          1611        2004   0.0    0.0     9.8   11.7
     distancesOneToMany  MapReduceTestStrictStrings                          1612        2000   4.5    6.3     9.8   11.6
      distance           MapReduceTestStrictStrings                          1613      499000   5.4    5.3     5.4    5.3
    hListToEOF           MapReduceTestStrictStrings                          1609       23996   0.9    0.6     3.6    0.6
     readTextDevice      Data.Text.IO.Internal                               1610        1660   2.7    0.0     2.7    0.0
 CAF:main4               Main                                                1591           1   0.0    0.0     0.0    0.0
 CAF:main5               Main                                                1590           1   0.0    0.0     0.0    0.0
  main                   Main                                                1608           0   0.0    0.0     0.0    0.0
 CAF                     GHC.Num                                             1580           1   0.0    0.0     0.0    0.0
 CAF                     GHC.IO.Handle.FD                                    1526           2   0.0    0.0     0.0    0.0
 CAF                     GHC.IO.FD                                           1510           2   0.0    0.0     0.0    0.0
 CAF                     System.Event.Thread                                 1508           3   0.0    0.0     0.0    0.0
 CAF                     GHC.IO.Encoding.Iconv                               1487           2   0.0    0.0     0.0    0.0
 CAF                     System.Event.Internal                               1486           2   0.0    0.0     0.0    0.0
 CAF                     System.Event.Unique                                 1483           1   0.0    0.0     0.0    0.0
 CAF                     GHC.Conc.Signal                                     1480           1   0.0    0.0     0.0    0.0
 CAF                     Data.Text.Internal                                   813           1   0.0    0.0     0.0    0.0
 CAF                     Data.Text.Array                                      811           1   0.0    0.0     0.0    0.0

Retainer sets created during profiling:
SET 2 = {<MAIN.SYSTEM>}
SET 3 = {<MapReduceTestStrictStrings.singleResultBatch,MapReduceTestStrictStrings.sumOfDistancesOnBigFileUsingBatches,Main.main>}
SET 15 = {<GHC.IO.FD.CAF>}
SET 17 = {<System.Event.Thread.CAF>}
SET 18 = {<>}
SET 44 = {<GHC.IO.Handle.FD.CAF>}
SET 47 = {<GHC.IO.Handle.FD.CAF>, <MAIN.SYSTEM>}
SET 56 = {<GHC.Conc.Signal.CAF>}
SET 57 = {<>, <MAIN.SYSTEM>}
SET 66 = {<MAIN.SYSTEM>, <MapReduceTestStrictStrings.singleResultBatch,MapReduceTestStrictStrings.sumOfDistancesOnBigFileUsingBatches,Main.main>}
SET 67 = {<System.Event.Thread.CAF>, <>, <MAIN.SYSTEM>}
SET 72 = {<GHC.Conc.Sync.CAF>, <MAIN.SYSTEM>}
SET 76 = {<MapReduceTestStrictStrings.hListToEOF,MapReduceTestStrictStrings.singleResultBatch,MapReduceTestStrictStrings.sumOfDistancesOnBigFileUsingBatches,Main.main>}
SET 81 = {<GHC.IO.Handle.FD.CAF>, <MAIN.SYSTEM>, <MapReduceTestStrictStrings.singleResultBatch,MapReduceTestStrictStrings.sumOfDistancesOnBigFileUsingBatches,Main.main>}
SET 83 = {<GHC.IO.Encoding.Iconv.CAF>, <GHC.IO.Handle.FD.CAF>, <MAIN.SYSTEM>, <MapReduceTestStrictStrings.singleResultBatch,MapReduceTestStrictStrings.sumOfDistancesOnBigFileUsingBatches,Main.main>}
SET 86 = {<GHC.Conc.Signal.CAF>, <>}
SET 95 = {<MapReduceTestStrictStrings.distancesOneToMany,MapReduceTestStrictStrings.distancesManyToMany,MapReduceTestStrictStrings.singleResultBatch,MapReduceTestStrictStrings.sumOfDistancesOnBigFileUsingBatches,Main.main>}
SET 96 = {<MAIN.SYSTEM>, <MapReduceTestStrictStrings.distancesOneToMany,MapReduceTestStrictStrings.distancesManyToMany,MapReduceTestStrictStrings.singleResultBatch,MapReduceTestStrictStrings.sumOfDistancesOnBigFileUsingBatches,Main.main>}
SET 100 = {<MapReduceTestStrictStrings.singleResultBatch,MapReduceTestStrictStrings.sumOfDistancesOnBigFileUsingBatches,Main.main>, <MapReduceTestStrictStrings.hListToEOF,MapReduceTestStrictStrings.singleResultBatch,MapReduceTestStrictStrings.sumOfDistancesOnBigFileUsingBatches,Main.main>}
SET 102 = {<MAIN.SYSTEM>, <MapReduceTestStrictStrings.singleResultBatch,MapReduceTestStrictStrings.sumOfDistancesOnBigFileUsingBatches,Main.main>, <MapReduceTestStrictStrings.distancesOneToMany,MapReduceTestStrictStrings.distancesManyToMany,MapReduceTestStrictStrings.singleResultBatch,MapReduceTestStrictStrings.sumOfDistancesOnBigFileUsingBatches,Main.main>}
SET 103 = {<MapReduceTestStrictStrings.sumOfDistancesOnBigFileUsingBatches,Main.main>}
SET 136 = {<GHC.IO.Handle.FD.CAF>, <MapReduceTestStrictStrings.singleResultBatch,MapReduceTestStrictStrings.sumOfDistancesOnBigFileUsingBatches,Main.main>}
SET 143 = {<GHC.Conc.Sync.CAF>, <GHC.IO.Handle.FD.CAF>, <MAIN.SYSTEM>}
SET 144 = {<MapReduceTestStrictStrings.distancesOneToMany,MapReduceTestStrictStrings.distancesSetToSet,MapReduceTestStrictStrings.singleResultBatch,MapReduceTestStrictStrings.sumOfDistancesOnBigFileUsingBatches,Main.main>}
SET 145 = {<MAIN.SYSTEM>, <MapReduceTestStrictStrings.distancesOneToMany,MapReduceTestStrictStrings.distancesSetToSet,MapReduceTestStrictStrings.singleResultBatch,MapReduceTestStrictStrings.sumOfDistancesOnBigFileUsingBatches,Main.main>}
SET 146 = {<MapReduceTestStrictStrings.distancesSetToSet,MapReduceTestStrictStrings.singleResultBatch,MapReduceTestStrictStrings.sumOfDistancesOnBigFileUsingBatches,Main.main>}
SET 147 = {<MAIN.SYSTEM>, <MapReduceTestStrictStrings.distancesSetToSet,MapReduceTestStrictStrings.singleResultBatch,MapReduceTestStrictStrings.sumOfDistancesOnBigFileUsingBatches,Main.main>}
SET 148 = {<MapReduceTestStrictStrings.distancesSetToSet,MapReduceTestStrictStrings.singleResultBatch,MapReduceTestStrictStrings.sumOfDistancesOnBigFileUsingBatches,Main.main>, <MapReduceTestStrictStrings.distancesOneToMany,MapReduceTestStrictStrings.distancesSetToSet,MapReduceTestStrictStrings.singleResultBatch,MapReduceTestStrictStrings.sumOfDistancesOnBigFileUsingBatches,Main.main>}
```

And the following .hp image:
[image: Retainer heap profile for 2k line file and 500line batches]

**EDIT 3:**
The previous code all used the packages:

```
Data.Text.IO
Data.Text
Data.Text.Read
```

When i use the lazy versions of them, the total time / memory / space usages doesn't really change: 2.62 secs, 2.25Gb allocations and 5.5MB space

**The accepted solution:**
The lazy versions did not work because the hListToEOF forced a full file read (I expected the : constructor to work lazily).

The solution is to use he following imports:

```
import qualified Data.ByteString.Char8 as Str
import qualified Data.Text.Lazy.IO as TextIO
import qualified Data.Text.Lazy as T 
import Data.Text.Lazy.Read
```

and in the *singleResultBatch* function the following modification:

```
                            readDistances = liftM  ( (map textRead . T.lines)) $ TextIO.readFile path
```

Then the both the speed (2.72s) and the memory allocations (2.3GB) do not change, which is expected.

The heap profile (space usage) does improve (1.8MB instead of 5.5MB), as visible in:
[image: heap profile when Text.Lazy packages are used]

Comment: Looks like you're using String-based IO. Can you switch to a more efficient type like Data.ByteString.Lazy or Text.Lazy -- both should allow incremental processing, in efficient pieces.

Comment: Can you run the **retainer** profiler, to see what functions are holding on to what data? http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/6.12.2/html/users_guide/prof-heap.html#retainer-prof

Comment: I'm using the following package `Data.Text.IO as Text`. I'll give the lazy one a try.

Comment: Don, do you get any wiser from the retainer data? I don't really see anything that indicates any problems.

Comment: If you get a different heap profile using `Data.Text.Lazy.IO` just update your question with the answer shown. http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/text/0.11.0.7/doc/html/Data-Text-Lazy-IO.html#g:2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to process data incrementally.  Currently, `hListToEOF` reads all the data in in one go, which you then slowly process (hence the initial memory spike as everything is read in, then a slow reduction as the list is deallocated).

Instead of doing your own IO via `hListToEOF`, read/stream the files lazily (e.g. with `readFile` from the Text.Lazy library) and map your processing functions over them.

Answer (score 0):

I think a big part of your problem is that you're holding on to lists, which are fairly inefficient space-wise if they need to be retained.  Try switching to a more compact storage mechanism, such as `Vector`.  This is a fairly direct translation of some of your functions, with probably a lot of space for optimizations:

```
sumOfDistancesOnSmallFile :: FilePath -> IO IntegersumOfDistancesOnSmallFile path = withFile path ReadMode $ \h->do
                          distances <- liftM ( V.fromList . (map textRead) ) $ hListToEOF Text.hGetLine h
                          let subSet = distances
                          let emptySubSet = V.null subSet
                          return $ if (emptySubSet)
                                           then (0)
                                           else (distancesManyToMany subSet)


distancesManyToMany :: V.Vector Integer -> Integer
distancesManyToMany mp0 = fst $ V.foldl' (\(!acc,mp) _ -> let (el,mp1) = (V.head mp, V.tail mp) in (acc+el,mp1)) (0,mp0) mp0

distancesOneToMany :: Integer -> V.Vector Integer -> Integer
distancesOneToMany one many = V.sum $ V.map (distance one) many
```

On my system, this will execute on a 10000 line file of test data in about 14s, with maximum memory usage of 125MB.